# How do I increment count when there are multiple instances of an item in the cart? I have to iterate over the existing AoH and return a new one

Tags: ruby

All this is returning is a new AoH(array of hashes) with all the items from the original AoH. Also, duplicate items have to appear only once in the new AoH with the count increased

```
groceries = [
  {:item => "AVOCADO", :price => 3.00, :clearance => true },
  {:item => "AVOCADO", :price => 3.00, :clearance => true },
  {:item => "KALE", :price => 3.00, :clearance => false}
]

def consolidate_cart(cart)

  new_array_of_hashes = []
  my_index = 0 

  while my_index < cart.length do 
    name = cart[my_index][:item]
    #new_array_of_hashes[my_index][:count] = 1
    if new_array_of_hashes[my_index]

      new_array_of_hashes[my_index][:count] += 1
    else
      new_array_of_hashes.push(cart[my_index])
      new_array_of_hashes[my_index][:count] = 1
    end
    my_index += 1 
  end
  new_array_of_hashes

end

consolidate_cart(groceries)
```

All this is returning is a new AoH(array of hashes) with all the items from the original AoH. Also, duplicate items have to appear only once in the new AoH with the count increased

Comment: If I understand the question, consider writing something like the following: `groceries = { "AVOCADO"=>{:price=>3.00, :clearance=>true, :quantity=>2}, "KALE"=>{:price=>3.00, :clearance=>false, quantity=>1}}`. Then to add `h = { :item=>X, :price=>Y, :clearance=>Z}` write `if groceries.key?(h[:item]); groceries[h[:item]][:quantity] += 1; else groceries[h[:item]] = {:price=>h[:price], :clearance=>h[:clearance], :quantity=>1}; end`. Once finished you could easily convert `groceries` to an array of hashes. (This can be done more elegantly.)

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to know what your expected output looks like. Don't describe it, show us.

Answer (score 1):

When using Ruby you generally don't want to manually iterate collections. Ruby offers a great amount of iterator methods, which mostly can be found in the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html) module, included by most collection classes like `Array`, `Hash`, `Set` and others. That being said, let's get to the answer.

You could group the items based upon the item itself, then count the total number of items present in each group.

```
groceries = [
  {:item => "AVOCADO", :price => 3.00, :clearance => true },
  {:item => "AVOCADO", :price => 3.00, :clearance => true },
  {:item => "KALE",    :price => 3.00, :clearance => false}
]

def consolidate_cart(cart)
  cart.group_by(&:itself).map { |item, items| item.merge(count: items.count) }
end

consolidate_cart(groceries)
#=> [{:item=>"AVOCADO", :price=>3.0, :clearance=>true,  :count=>2},
#    {:item=>"KALE",    :price=>3.0, :clearance=>false, :count=>1}]
```

This only groups items with the exact same keys-value pairs together. Meaning that if there is an item:

```
{:item => "AVOCADO", :price => 2.00, :clearance => false}
```

It will be placed in a different group than:

```
{:item => "AVOCADO", :price => 3.00, :clearance => true}
```

References:

- [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [`Object#itself`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-itself)
- [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)
- [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-merge)
- [`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-count)

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!